# Show different theme for admin?

Tags: themes, testing

I'd like to test some theme changes on my live site, but I obviously don't want regular users seeing any errors that may arise from it. I'd like to just duplicate my theme folder and if I'm logged in as admin, then that theme is shown to me, otherwise, the old theme is shown to my users.

Is there a plugin to do this?

Comment: You can use Theme Switch and Preview to do this. http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/nkthemeswitch/

Comment: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/theme-test-drive/ does exactly what you want

Comment: At the moment (November 2018) the only plugin that is updated is [Theme Switcha](https://wordpress.org/plugins/theme-switcha/). I found it considering the list of theme-switcher plugins reported by the article [How to Develop WordPress Themes Behind the Scenes](https://digwp.com/2009/12/develop-themes-behind-the-scenes/)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I just wrote this quick plugin and it seems to work. Let me know if there is a better way.

```
<?php

/*
Plugin Name: Theme Switch if Admin
Description: Display different theme to user if logged in as admin
Author: Kyle Barber
*/
    add_filter('template', 'change_theme');
    add_filter('option_template', 'change_theme');
    add_filter('option_stylesheet', 'change_theme');
    function change_theme($theme) {
        if ( current_user_can('manage_options') ) {
            $theme = 'twentyeleven';
        }

        return $theme;
    }
```

Comment: Small hint, the plugin [User Theme](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/user-theme/) in the official repo have a small plugin for this job, but without options, same solution how this answer.

Comment: This is an awesome little plugin. Thank you for sharing.

Answer (score 1):

You got [`switch_theme()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/switch_theme) and `current_user_can( 'manage_options' );`, which will only trigger for admin accounts.