# How to load a different theme for categories?

Tags: themes, switch-theme

I need to load a completely different theme for my categories. My search came up with `switch_theme` function but it changes the theme permanently while I only need the theme change only occur on my category pages.

Then I found [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/49223/show-different-theme-for-admin).

```
add_filter( 'template', 'my_change_theme' );
add_filter( 'option_template', 'my_change_theme' );
add_filter( 'option_stylesheet', 'my_change_theme' );

function my_change_theme($theme)
{
    if ( is_category() )
        $theme = 'theme_for_cats';

    return $theme;
}
```

The problem with this one is, it only loads the correct stylesheet. The markup stays the same as my default theme.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I can't imagine in what scenario this would be easier than accommodating the different layouts/styles in your primary active theme. I suspect you are making life hard for yourself with this.

Comment: Consider that I have both themes previously made and ready. I just want to load the second theme for my categories and I don't want to spend time on accommodations. Thanks.

Comment: Ehem, nobody knows how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after some consideration and tinkering I could get it to work.
The reason it wasn't working was because the needed procedures for loading a template kick in long before the the parser gets to `functions.php` of the theme. So to overcome this I had to bring the code into the plugins' section.
By creating a plugin the needed filters are called in time therefore the theme gets changed correctly.